# how to replace words with python bing spell correcter suggestions

Tags: python, json, spell-checking, bing-api

I used bing API in python for spell correction. although i get the correct Json format with suggestions it doesn't replace the original string. I tried with data.replace, but it doesn't work. is there any other simple method available to replace original string with suggested words.

```
import httplib,urllib,base64
headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '7fdf55a1a7e42d0a7890bab142343f8'
}

params = urllib.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
    'text': 'Lectures were really good. There were lot of people who came their without any Java knowledge and yet you were very suppor.',
    'mode': 'proof',
    'preContextText': '{string}',
    'postContextText': '{string}',
    'mkt': '{string}',
})

try:
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
    conn.request("GET", "/bing/v5.0/spellcheck/?%s" % params, "{body}", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

output (pretty printed):

```
{'_type': 'SpellCheck',
 'flaggedTokens': [{'offset': 61,
                    'suggestions': [{'score': 0.854956767552189,
                                     'suggestion': 'there'}],
                    'token': 'their',
                    'type': 'UnknownToken'},
                   {'offset': 116,
                    'suggestions': [{'score': 0.871971469417366,
                                     'suggestion': 'support'}],
                    'token': 'suppor',
                    'type': 'UnknownToken'}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the replacements yourself in your text.

You can iterate the 'flaggedTokens', get the offset of each token, find the best suggestion and replace the token by the suggestion:

```
import operator


text = 'Lectures were really good. There were lot of people who came their without any Java knowledge and yet you were very suppor.'

data = {'_type': 'SpellCheck',
        'flaggedTokens': [{'offset': 61,
                'suggestions': [{'score': 0.854956767552189,
                                 'suggestion': 'there'}],
                'token': 'their',
                'type': 'UnknownToken'},
               {'offset': 116,
                'suggestions': [{'score': 0.871971469417366,
                                 'suggestion': 'support'}],
                'token': 'suppor',
                'type': 'UnknownToken'}]}

shifting = 0
correct = text
for ft in data['flaggedTokens']:
    offset = ft['offset']
    suggestions = ft['suggestions']
    token = ft['token']

    # find the best suggestion
    suggestions.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('score'), reverse=True)
    substitute = suggestions[0]['suggestion']

    # replace the token by the suggestion
    before = correct[:offset + shifting]
    after = correct[offset + shifting + len(token):]
    correct = before + substitute + after
    shifting += len(substitute) - len(token)

print(correct)
```

You get: “Lectures were really good. There were lot of people who came there without any Java knowledge and yet you were very support.”